# TypeScript error handling an unknown variable: Property does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand how to properly approach handling an **unknown** variable, which may be an object with certain properties I can use. This derives from a variety of try/catch scenarios when working with a third party library which is still in development, so "e" may or may not be an object with certain properties.

Below is a simplified version of my question, but there are other manifestations of the issue. Therefore, **I wish to avoid type assertions or disable type checking**. What I'm looking for is a proper way to check an "unknown" value to see if it is an object with certain properties.

Why is the following if condition insufficient? TypeScript just views it as an unknown object and isn't use the info I've passed to ensure (1) it is an **object**, (2) it is **not null**, and (3) it **has the key "errNum"**.

What other possible condition could cause *"console.log(e.errNum)"* to throw an error at runtime after all of these checks? This fails both in the VSCode GUI and when building with webpack 5 (using eslint after recent migration from tslint). I can't think of any other edge cases that would cause problems at runtime.

```
try {
    const err = { errNum: 12 };
    throw err;
} catch (e) {
    // e is inferred as unknown, as it should be
    if (e && typeof e === 'object' && 'errNum' in e) console.log(e.errNum); // TS error: Property 'errNum' does not exist on type 'object'.
}
```

Comment: Looking to avoid too many type assertions if possible. For example, the following would work, but gets very verbose: ```else if (e) errorMessage += `\n\n${typeof e === 'object' && (e as AnyObject)?.message ? (e as AnyObject).message : (e as AnyObject).toString()}`;```

Answer (score 5):

You will not be able to take advantage of the type checker's inference capabilities because the catch clause variable is unknown.  In this case the easier things might be to use the condition to determine that `errNum` is property in a type guard function.

```
catch (e)
{
  if (isErrorNumObj(e)) console.log(e.errNum);
}

function isErrorNumObj<T>(obj: T): obj is T & { errNum: unknown } {
  return obj && 'errNum' in obj;
}
```

You can even make a more generic version that can accept any number of props.

```
try {
  const err = { errNum: 12, stackTrace: 'abc' };
  throw err;
} catch (e: unknown) {

  if (hasProps(e, 'errNum', 'stackTrace')) {
    console.log(e.errNum, e.stackTrace);
  }
}

function hasProps<T, U extends string | number | symbol>(obj: T, ...propName: U[]): obj is T & { [P in U]: unknown } {
  return !!obj // ensure not nullish.
    && (typeof obj == "object" || typeof obj == "function") // ensure not primitive.
    && propName.every(x => x in obj); // ensure every prop is in obj.
}
```

Comment: I see a type error in the `hasProps` function shown. Error at `x in obj` "Type 'NonNullable<T>' may represent a primitive value, which is not permitted as the right operand of the 'in' operator."

Comment: Thanks @vhs. That probably wasn't an issue the compiler detected when this answer was written.  I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'd create a user defined [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates).

```
function isErrNum(x: any): x is { errNum: number } {
    return !!x && 'errNum' in x;
}

try {
    const err = { errNum: 12 };
    throw err;
} catch (e: unknown) {
    // e is inferred as unknown, as it should be
    if (isErrNum(e)) {
        console.log(e.errNum);
    }
}
```

We extract our "test" code into a function that returns "variable is type". And a "true" return then informs the compiler that in the context of that being true, the object is that declared type and *is not* that type in an `else`.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgUQE4YHIgLYAUAHgFyICGYAngJRlHIqIDeiAplrnmWPgEYdEAXxYBYAFCIpiDGyggMSAIRKGAMjWIA5Bxz4tyJEQDcEoRIlQMVMZOkQEKKOyyIAvCxd7uiAIwAmYVM7KSgACww4AHcvYJEIcigIMMQCNjJwAGswaLAaW2lEAHoi9kZDYF02ABMKJiycqLAAGjrkZxQwuBAAG1qBCUKYYFTUTG80mnzmQcL7RzgetgA6HrgAczTl3S4aYMLzcSEgA)

Answer (score 1):

In typescript the `in` operator can be used as a type guard, to allow the compiler to narrow down a type in a union type: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing

However, in your case as `e` is inferred to be of `object` type which is not a union type, so even after applying `errNum in e`, it remains an `object` type instead of being inferred as `{errNum: number}`

What you could do instead is define a custom error class like so:

```
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor(readonly errNum: number) {
    super()
  }
}
```

use it to construct your error:

```
throw new MyError(10)
```

then narrow its type using `instanceof`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#instanceof-narrowing

```
catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof MyError) {
    console.log(e.errNum)
  }
}
```